# How to save user inputted data to a text file

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm trying to write a program to create a text file which contains a sequence of test scores, once there done it will ask for a file name used to save the scores.

Then I need to ask them for a name of a file, and then grab the ints out of said file, and then fill the array.

I'm pretty sure I can do the second part, but I'm having some trouble with the first part. If needed i can put the code I have for the second part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think asking this as a question on Stack Overflow is the right way for you. At least first search for answers and examples, there should be plenty to be found. If somehow that’s not enough to get you through, please show us what you tried and explain how you failed — that could make for a very different and much more interesting Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm)

To actually get the test scores from the text file, you can look into Scanner or StringTokenizer.